# How to keep the same offset in different iphone models in SwiftUI

Tags: iphone, swiftui

I'm making an app and the preview is in iPhone 14, and its fine, but when I switch to iPhone 8, the offsets are wrong. What is the best way to tackle this?

My code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct CustomColor {
    static let lead = Color("lead")
    // Add more here...
}

struct playback: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
           
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(CustomColor.lead).frame(width: 393, height: 350).offset(x: 0,y: 350).ignoresSafeArea()
                            
            ProgressView(value: 0.5).tint(.white).background(.gray).frame(width: 340).offset(y: 310)

                SongImage(image: Image("grad")).offset(x: -140, y: 240)
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Flashing lights").font(.title2).offset(y:225)
                Text("Kanye West").offset(y:230)
            }
            VStack{
                Text("1:24").foregroundColor(.gray).shadow(color: .black, radius: 3).font(.system(size: 15)).offset(x:-152,y:335)
                Text("2:30").foregroundColor(.gray).shadow(color: .black, radius: 3).font(.system(size: 15)).offset(x:150,y:315)
            }
            Image(systemName: "pause.fill").tint(.gray)
                    .font(.system(size: 50)).offset(x:0,y:360)
                Image(systemName: "forward.fill").font(.system(size: 40)).offset(x:100,y: 360)
                Image(systemName: "backward.fill").font(.system(size: 40)).offset(x:-100,y: 360)
                            
            
                    
            
        }
        
        }
        
    }


struct playback_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        playback()
    }
}
```

What I want in iPhone 8:

[image: What i want in Iphone 8]

What I am getting in iPhone 8:

[image: What i am Getting in Iphone 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing is: **don't use offset for layout.**

In this case, I would suggest you use a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack` and then make adjustments to layout by using padding. You can also use a `Spacer` to fill gaps.

Like this:

```swift
struct Playback: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    SongImage(image: Image("grad"))

                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Flashing lights")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Text("Kanye West")
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 20)

                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()

                ProgressView(value: 0.5)
                    .tint(.white)
                    .background(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal)

                HStack {
                    Text("1:24")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2:30")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)

                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    Image(systemName: "backward.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                    Image(systemName: "pause.fill")
                        .tint(.gray)
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                    Image(systemName: "forward.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
            .background(
                CustomColor.lead
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                        CustomColor.lead
                            .frame(height: 10)
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: MusicPlayer]

Comment: Thanks A lot, I have tried it and tho i have not completely fixed everything, it has given me a direction and an important lesson XD. Thanks Again

Comment: You're welcome